# How to make a query cast for each row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that takes the `GeoJSON` value from a column on the last row, the value is converted to geometry and update other column on the same row with this new value.

```
UPDATE table-name 
SET geometria = (SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
         ST_AsText(
           CAST(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(t1.column-name) AS TEXT)
         ), 4326
       )
FROM (SELECT column-name
      FROM table-name
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS t1)
WHERE id IN(SELECT id
      FROM table-name
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1
);
```

Right now i only take the last row inserted, how can i use this query with a trigger where the query would be used for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use simple sintax:

```
UPDATE table-name 
SET geometria = (SELECT ST_GeomFromText( ST_AsText( CAST(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(column-name) AS TEXT) ), 4326 )
```

So you update every col with some function

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the following error happened:
`syntax error at or near "END"`

Comment: Can you give me an example  of record converting?

Comment: Actually, i did manage to run your sugestion and create the function, with your sugestion, and trigger:
`
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON pracas_web.pracas_formulario
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_formulario();

`
But when i tested it with a insert from my php form, it showd a message error.